# Spring Integration: how to process multiple messages at one time?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-integration, message-queue

I have the following configuration:

```
<bean id="mongoDbMessageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactoryDefault"/>
</bean>

<!-- the queue capacity is unbounded as it uses a persistent store-->
<int:channel id="logEntryChannel">
    <int:queue message-store="mongoDbMessageStore"/>
</int:channel>

<!-- the poller will process 10 messages every 6 seconds -->
<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="logEntryChannel" ref="logEntryPostProcessorReceiver" method="handleMessage">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="10" fixed-rate="6000"/>
</int:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

And the message handler defined as

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
    Object payload = message.getPayload();
    if (payload instanceof LogEntry) {
        LogEntry logEntry = (LogEntry) payload;
        String app = (String) message.getHeaders().get("app");
        logger.info("LogEntry Received - " + app + " " + logEntry.getEntityType() + " " + logEntry.getAction() + " " + logEntry.getEventTime());
        logEntryPostProcessService.postProcess(app, logEntry);
    } else {
        throw new MessageRejectedException(message, "Unknown data type has been received.");
    }
}
```

What I would like to have is something like

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(List<Message<?>> messages) throws MessagingException {
...
}
```

so basically the poller sends all the 10 messages in one call instead of calling the method 10 times one per messages.

The reason for this is to have the possibility to bulk process all the messages in chunk therefore improving performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's true, because of (`AbstractPollingEndpoint`):

```
taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        while (initialized && (maxMessagesPerPoll <= 0 || count < maxMessagesPerPoll)) {
...
            if (!pollingTask.call()) {
                break;
            }
...
    }
});
```

Hence all your messages (`max-messages-per-poll`) are handled within the same thread.
However they are sent to handler one by one and not as an entire bunch.

To process the in parallel you should use `ExecutorChannel` before your `logEntryPostProcessorReceiver`. Something like this:

```
<channel id="executorChannel">
   <dispatcher task-executor="threadPoolExecutor"/>
</channel>

<bridge input-channel="logEntryChannel" output-channel="executorChannel">
   <poller max-messages-per-poll="10" fixed-rate="6000"/>
</bridge>

<outbound-channel-adapter channel="executorChannel" ref="logEntryPostProcessorReceiver" method="handleMessage"/>
```

**UPDATE**

To process messages as one batch you should `aggregate` them. Since they all are result of `polling endpoint`, there is no `sequenceDetails` in the messages. You can overcome it with some fake value for `correlationId`:

```
<aggregator correlation-strategy-expression="T(Thread).currentThread().id"
        release-strategy-expression="size() == 10"/>
```

Where `size() == 10` should be equal to `max-messages-per-poll`.

After that your `logEntryPostProcessorReceiver` has to apply the `list` of `payload`s. Or just one message, which `payload` is a list as a result from `<aggregator>`.

Comment: In my case I'd like to have all the polled messages as one batch because it will be faster to process them at once. However I learned something new, a way of handling messages in parallel.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Artem Bilan, here the final solution:

```
<bean id="mongoDbMessageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactoryDefault"/>
</bean>

<!-- the queue capacity is unbounded as it uses a persistent store-->
<int:channel id="logEntryChannel">
    <int:queue message-store="mongoDbMessageStore"/>
</int:channel>

<!-- 
    the poller will process 100 messages every minute 
    if the size of the group is 100 (the poll reached the max messages) or 60 seconds time out (poll has less than 100 messages) then the payload with the list of messages is passed to defined output channel
-->
<int:aggregator input-channel="logEntryChannel" output-channel="logEntryAggrChannel"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
    group-timeout="60000"
    correlation-strategy-expression="T(Thread).currentThread().id"
    release-strategy-expression="size() == 100">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="100" fixed-rate="60000"/>
</int:aggregator>

<int:channel id="logEntryAggrChannel"/>        

<!-- the payload is a list of log entries as result of the aggregator -->
<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="logEntryAggrChannel" ref="logEntryPostProcessorReceiver" method="handleMessage"/>
```

As per comment (in the code above), I had to set group-timeout/send-partial-result-on-expiry as some groups were formed with a Thread ID but never processed because they didn't reach the condition of size == 100.